# Create bar plot for every level of a factor in a wide format data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a bar plot using ggplot2 and my data is in this format:

[image]

`dput` here:

```
structure(list(clade = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("19A", 
"20A", "20B", "20E (EU1)", "20I (Alpha, V1)", "20J (Gamma, V3)", 
"21J (Delta)"), class = "factor"), C.T = c(0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), 
    A.G = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), G.A = c(0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0), G.C = c(0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0), T.C = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), C.A = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), G.T = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), A.T = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), T.A = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T.G = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), A.C = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), C.G = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0), A.del = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TAT.del = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), TCTGGTTTT.del = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TACATG.del = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), AGTTCA.del = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), GATTTC.del = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000014b25a51ef0>)
```

I'd like to create 7 bar plots (one for each "clade") where the X axis would have the columns of the data frame (C.T would be 1 bar, A.G would be another bar, etc) and the Y axis would be the count. Essentially, for each clade, print a barplot with the counts of column.

For example, for the bar plot of the clade "20B" and the bar name "C.T" the count would be the sum of the values from the data frame. Can I do that in this wide format? Do I need to transform the data to a long format instead?

I was trying to apply this SO answer: [Plotting error bar on bar chart for a data frame in wide format using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65028815/plotting-error-bar-on-bar-chart-for-a-data-frame-in-wide-format-using-ggplot) but I keep getting `choose another strategy with names_repair`

Thank you in advance, any help is very welcome!

Comment: OP, can you share the code you are using in the body of your question, please?

Comment: I was trying simething like this: `data_long = pivot_longer(snv_data, cols = names(snv_data)[2:ncol(snv_data)], names_to = "clade", values_to = "snv")`

Comment: There is already a column named `clade` in your dataframe. That's why `names_to = "clade"` will not work. Use a different name and as a shortcut you could use `cols = -clade` in `pivot_longer`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked now!